# Python. Регулярные выражения. Обрезать строку

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
#Это типа pars.txt
93.180.71.3 - - [17/May/2015:08:05:32 +0000] "GET /downloads/product_1 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21)"
93.180.71.3 - - [17/May/2015:08:05:23 +0000] "GET /downloads/product_1 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21)"
80.91.33.133 - - [17/May/2015:08:05:24 +0000] "GET /downloads/product_1 HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.17)"
217.168.17.5 - - [17/May/2015:08:05:34 +0000] "GET /downloads/product_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 490 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.10.3)"
217.168.17.5 - - [17/May/2015:08:05:09 +0000] "GET /downloads/product_2 HTTP/1.1" 200 490 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.10.3)"
```

```
import re

with open('pars.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        pars_line = re.match(r'[0-9.]{0,}', line)
        pars_line_2 = re.match(r'\[#Проблема тут\]', line)
        print(pars_line.group())
        print(pars_line_2.group())
```

Необходимо сохранить в pars_line_2 то, что находится в квадратных скобках и вывести на экран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно все понял, в pars_line_2 можно сохранить то что находится в квадратных скобках, например [17/May/2015:08:05:32 +0000] следующей регуляркой:

```
pars_line_2=re.match(r'(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})(\s-\s-\s)\[(.*)\]', line)
print(pars_line_2.group(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, что же требуется в конечном итоге.

```
from pathlib import Path
from re import findall

Path(r'X:\path\result.txt').write_text("\n".join(findall('\[(.+)\]', Path(r'X:\path\pars.txt').read_text())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь сделать так. Сначала создать список с помощью split(), а потом вывести вторую переменную из списка.
Пример:

```
test_list_1 = your_text.split("[")
test_list_2 = test_list_1[1].split("]")
print(test_list_2[1]
```

Надеюсь помог!